# Doubt regarding approach to question: In how many ways could $4$ boys and $4$ girls be arranged so that no two girls are together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question is in how many ways could you arrange 4 boys and 4 girls in a row such that no 2 girls are together?

My doubt, however, is that if I were to find all possible arrangements, could I conclude that the total arrangements would be all possible arrangements (i.e. $8!$) - ( total arrangements with exactly $4$ girls together + total arrangements with exactly $3$ girls together + total arrangements with exactly $2$ girls together). If so, what would be the correct approach ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct but tedious. Another approach is as follows$:$

First place the four boys in the row. Number of ways to do this is $4!.$ Now there are $5$ gaps formed ($3$ in between the boys while $2$ next to the boys at the end position) Like this

$\displaystyle  \cdots B_{1} \ \cdots  B_{2}\ \cdots B_3\ \cdots\ B_4\ \cdots $

Now we have to arrange all girls in these gaps formed as no two girls can be together. Number of ways to do this is $\binom{5}{4}4!$

So total number of ways are $$4!\binom{5}{4}4!$$

Comment: This is obviously a much better approach but I am unable to arrive at the correct answer when I use the former method.Just wanted to know what mistake I may have made in my calculations

Comment: @VenomSnake You have not said what your calculations were with *"all possible arrangements (i.e. **8!**) - ( total arrangements with exactly **4** girls together + total arrangements with exactly **3** girls together + total arrangements with exactly **2** girls together)"*, though perhaps you ignored or overcounted the possibility of two pairs of two girls together

Comment: @VenomSnake "*just wanted to know what mistake I may have made in my calculations*"  It is hard to speculate just what you could have done wrong when you didn't show us any calculations, but probable errors would be things such as "3 girls together" might have included things like $G_1 (G_2G_3G_4)B_1B_2B_3B_4$ where, yes you had three girls together but this outcome was already counted in the 4 girls together scenario... or making mistakes such as with the "2 girls together" case as things like missing having multiple groups of 2 girls $(G_1G_2)B_1(G_3G_4)B_2B_3B_4$

Comment: I actually did take into account all those cases.Let me just go through my calculations once again.Will let you know if I stumble at some point.Thanks btw

Comment: @VenomSnake . To check your numbers, you can use the same method MathStackexchangeIsNot provided.  There are $4!\binom 51 4!$ ways to have the 4 girls together.  $4!\binom{5}{1}\binom 41 4!$ ways to have exactly 3 girls together, $4!\binom 51\binom 42 4!$ ways to have exactly 2 girls together, $4!\binom 52 4!$ ways to have two pairs of two girls together, and $4!\binom 5 4 4!$ ways to have all singletons of girls separate.
$$\binom 51+\binom 51\binom 41+\binom51\binom 42+\binom52+\binom 54=\binom 84$$

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell for sure since you didn't provide your calculations, but the most likely mistake you made is double-counting some of the "bad" cases by failing to properly use the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  Here's a solution using that method.

Without constraints, there are $8!$ possible arrangements.  We need to subtract off all combinations that include consecutive girls.  There are $\binom 43$ ways to choose $2$ girls who will be next to each other and $2$ ways to arrange them.  Treat them as a unit and there are $7!$ ways (each of which is "bad") to arrange each of the units.  However, this double-counts "bad" combinations because in $2 \cdot 6!$ of those combinations, the remaining $2$ girls also will be next to each other so we have counted those combinations twice -- once for each pair of consecutive girls.  That means we have tentatively identified $12 \cdot 7!-2 \cdot 6! =82 \cdot 6!$ bad combinations.

Here's where the principle of inclusion and exclusion comes in.  This is still an overcount of "bad" combinations because when $3$ girls are consecutive, we will double-count those "bad" combinations.  There are $24$ ways to arrange $3$ of the $4$ girls consecutively.  Treat them as a unit and there are $6!$ combinations with $3$ consecutive girls.  That means we need to add back $24 \cdot 6!$ combinations, so now we're only subtracting off $48 \cdot 6!$ combinations.

But once again we have overcorrected.  We need to add back (to the count of "bad" combinations) the number of combinations in which all $4$ girls are consecutive.  There are $24$ ways to arrange the girls as a unit, and treating them as a unit, there are $24 \cdot 5!= 4 \cdot 6!$ such combinations.  So in total, we're subtracting $52 \cdot 6!$ "bad" combinations.

The answer, therefore, is $8!-52 \cdot 6!=(56-52) \cdot 6!=4 \cdot 6!=2880$ good combinations, which agrees with the much simpler calculation provided by @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ be $4$ boys and $G_1,G_2,G_3,G_4$ be $4$ girls.

Then any $2$ girls not together when they lie on

Gap of boys

So we have arrange $4$ boys like this

$\displaystyle  \cdots B_{1} \ \cdots  B_{2}\ \cdots B_3\ \cdots\ B_4\ \cdots $

We have arrange $4$ boys in $4!$ ways

Bow we have $5$ gaps, So we first select $4$ gap for $4$ girls and arrange $4$ girls in these $4$ girls

So ways $\displaystyle \binom{5}{4}\cdot 4!=5\times 4!$

So total ways $\displaystyle =4!\times 5\times 4!=5\cdot(4!)^2$

Comment: Does this add anything new to the existing answer, not being rude but just asking$?$